# Kubernetes / Java - how to verify a service account token?

Tags: java, authentication, kubernetes

I'm trying to port the following Go code to Java:

```
func verifyToken(clientId string) (bool, error) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    tr := authv1.TokenReview{
        Spec: authv1.TokenReviewSpec{
            Token:     clientId,
            Audiences: []string{"server"},
        },
    }
    result, err := kClientset.AuthenticationV1().TokenReviews().Create(ctx, &tr, metav1.CreateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    log.Printf("%s\n", prettyPrint(result.Status))

    if result.Status.Authenticated {
        return true, nil
    }
    return false, nil

}
```

However, I'm having a hard time finding the equivalent Java implementation for several of the references. For example, the `AuthenticationV1Api(client)` creates an authentication client, but the call to `createTokenReview` takes completely different parameters (e.g. `dryRun`).

To give a bit more context, I'm trying to share a server side service account token with a caller using token volume projection, so the server can authenticate the client.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first parameter in Java is the same as the second in go - a TokenReview object. The other parameters in Java are just flattened into seperate arguments rather than a single options struct in Go

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else, here is some Kotlin code calling k8s openapi:

```
private fun verifyToken(client: ApiClient, clientToken: String): V1TokenReview? {
    val tokenReviewSpec = V1TokenReviewSpec()
    tokenReviewSpec.token = clientToken
    tokenReviewSpec.audiences = listOf("server")

    val tokenReview = V1TokenReview()
    tokenReview.spec = tokenReviewSpec

    val authClient = AuthenticationV1Api(client)

    return authClient.createTokenReview(tokenReview, null, null, null, null)
}
```

Very important, this is how you create the client:

```
    val client = ClientBuilder.standard().build()
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client)
```